# Logic For Dynamic Sql Query Switching Content Source

Tags: php, mysql

I would like some help to write some SQL logic.

I currently have a scrapy bot collecting news on 10 sites.

News is updated daily on these sites.

I download them into an internal system, I need the news not to be shown by repeated sources.

It needs to work the same as Google Discover, randomizing the display of these news across news source sites.

It currently looks like this:

```
NEWS 1 : SITE A
NEWS 2 : SITE A
NEWS 3 : SITE A

NEWS 4: SITE B
NEWS 5: SITE B

NEWS 6: SITE C
NEWS 7: SITE C
```

I need this order to be more random, more fluid.

My system is in PHP / MYSQL.

Could you help me work out this logic? I'm lost on that, the dates are all the same day, and there's no hourly variation, just the entire date.

Comment: I cant understand your situation very well ,  if you choose the site randomly and then choose a random news from it , then u have a fully random displaying system, so where is the problem now ?

Comment: If you have stored the data in a mySQL table, you can ask mysql to output them in a random order

Answer (score 0):

assuming you obtain all the news in a proper select eg: using UNION
you could try using order by rand()

```
select * from (
    select news, 'site A' site 
    from table_site_A
    union 
    select news, 'site b' site 
    from table_site_b
    ....
    select news, 'site N' site 
    from table_site_N

) t
order by rand()
```